# Angular Maps DrawManager instance in Custom Control

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-directive

I having the diffuculty to create a custom control in order to change drawMode of the map in the Angular Google Maps library.

My markup is this

```
                <ui-gmap-google-map id="map" center="map.center" pan="map.pan" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" refresh="map.refresh" options="map.options" events="map.events" bounds="map.bounds" dorebuildall="true">
                <ui-gmap-map-control template="js/app/templates/mapToolbar.tpl.html" position="top-right" controller="mapWidgetCtrl"></ui-gmap-map-control>
                    <ui-gmap-polygons models="map.polygons" clickable="true" draggable="true" editable="true" dorebuildall="true"></ui-gmap-polygons>
                <ui-gmap-markers models="mapMarkers" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'" events="clickEventsObject"></ui-gmap-markers>
                <ui-gmap-drawing-manager options="drawingManagerOptions" control="drawingManagerControl" events="drawEventHandler"></ui-gmap-drawing-manager>

            </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

And my controllers are these (writing most relevant parts of code)

```
    app.controller('mapSearchCtrl', ["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.map = {
        center: {
            latitude: 40,
            longitude: 20
        },
        zoom: 9,
        bounds: {},
        polygons: {},
        options: {
            panControl: false,
            zoomControl: true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM
            },
            mapTypeControl: false,
            disableDefaultUI: true
        }
    };

    $scope.drawingManagerOptions = {

        drawingMode: null,
        drawingControl: true,
        drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes: [
                    google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
                ]
        },
        polygonOptions: {
            strokeWeight: 3,
            editable: true
        }
    };
    $scope.drawingManagerControl = {};

    $scope.options = {};

    $scope.mapMarkers = [];

    $scope.clickEventsObject = {
        mouseover: markerMouseOver,
        mouseout: markerMouseOut
    };

    $scope.drawEventHandler = {
        polygoncomplete: polygonComplete
    };

 function polygonComplete(drawingManager, eventName, scope, args) {
//$scope.drawingManagerControl.getDrawingManager().setDrawingMode(null); works here
//code...

});
```

[etc]..

And the other controller for the template with custom controls is:

```
    app.controller('mapWidgetCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.toogleMap = function() {    
        console.log('Change map view via drawingManager');
    };

}]);
```

I am having a difficutly into changing map view manually in both controllers (can't pass it somehow from one to another either). It seems I can't find a way to get the instance of drawManager outside of anything except polygonComplete function.

Any advice would be helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could introduce a [service](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/docs/guide/services) to **share** Drawing Manager Control across controllers:

```
app.service('sharedMapProperties', function () {
    var drawingManagerControl = {};

    return {
        setDrawingManagerControl: function (value) {
            drawingManagerControl = value;
        },
        getDrawingManagerControl: function () {
            return drawingManagerControl;
        }
    }
});
```

Now you could save the control (`drawingManagerControl` variable) once the map is initialized:

```
app.controller('mapSearchCtrl', function ($scope, uiGmapIsReady, sharedMapProperties) {

    //the remaining code is omitted..


    $scope.drawingManagerControl = {};
    sharedMapProperties.setDrawingManagerControl($scope.drawingManagerControl);


});
```

and then get control once the button clicked:

```
app.controller('mapWidgetCtrl', ['$scope', 'sharedMapProperties', function ($scope, sharedMapProperties) {
    $scope.toogleMap = function () {
        var control = sharedMapProperties.getDrawingManagerControl();
        var drawingManager = control.getDrawingManager();
        drawingManager.setDrawingMode(google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE);
        console.log('Change map view via drawingManager');
    };
}]);
```

[**Working example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/YvT2OiHExPhn0x28OQaI?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you very much! I had to put   sharedMapProperties.setDrawingManagerControl($scope.drawingManagerControl); in a  uiGmapIsReady.promise() in order to get it work but it was just want I needed!